# Editing a topic and its sub entries at the same time

Tags: django, forms, model, instance, edit

I want to edit an entry and it's child at the same time.

So I have a Price model which has Entry (another model) as it's foreign key.

```
class Price(models.Model):
    price = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    ptext = models.FloatField(blank = True, null = True) 
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'prices'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ptext[:50] + "..."  `
```

How would I pull the price from the entry model?

I can only modify data inside the entry model, but not the price model. The instance part is giving a problem in particular. I don't know what to put for the PriceForm instance.

```
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
   entry = Entry.objects.get(id = entry_id)
   price = entry.price_set.get.all() 
   topic = entry.topic

   check_topic_owner(topic.owner, request.user)  


   if request.method != 'POST':

      form = EntryForm(instance = entry)
      form2 = PriceForm(instance = price) 

   else: 

      form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data = request.POST)
      form2 = PriceForm(instance=price, data = request.POST)

      if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():

        form.save() 
        form2.save() 

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))



    context = {'entry': entry, 'topic': topic, 'form': form, 'form2':form2}

    return render(request, 'learning_logs/edit_entry.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the **price** objects from the **entry** object, you should use

```
price = entry.price_set.all()
```

instead of

```
price = entry.price_set.get.all()
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. I just had to use price = entry.price_set.get.first() since there was only a single variable inside the price object.